# Qt msvc2013 building with vs2015

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015

Hi I have updated visual studio to 2015 version and I have Qt msvc2013. Qt says that no compilers can make code for this version of Qt, (Qt detected compilers from visual studio). How can I make it working without installing VS2013?

Comment: Try to build from source. You can have problems with QWebkit because some additional libraries are required for it. In case try to build without it and add it later. You can find building informations here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html

Comment: [It was taken care of](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/109362/), update your Qt version.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm using Qt 5.5.0, any chances to be an update soon?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea attempting to build qt with msvc 2015 atm. There are no guides (working or not) and, from my experience, it's more work than you'd really want to do. way more

Comment: When I built qt with msvc 2013 (when there was no pre-built version) I had to manually fix headers and do more of black magic to perform the feat. I am not doing the same with 2015 :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot mix C++ compiled with different major versions of the Microsoft Visual C++ compilers. So you need to either get a version of Qt for Visual Studio 2015, or compile your own one.

At this time, there is not yet an official build of Qt for Visual Studio 2015 available (this is planned for Qt <strike>5.5.1</strike> 5.6.0). If you want to try compiling yourself, https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git is a comprehensive guide. You should try either the 5.5 branch (if you get the Qt sources from git), or the 5.5.0 source packages. You should be able to get help e.g. on the qt-interest mailing list.

Comment: Thank you for this information, I will wait for 5.5.1. Now I will Install VS 2013 and work with it.

Comment: If that helps, I posted an article that explains how to build Qt 5.5.1 (with QtWebkit) with Visual Studio 2015: http://goo.gl/Cfjkb6

Answer (score 2):

Adding a new mkspec is pretty simple, just copy the win32-msvc2013 and rename it to win32-msvc2015, then modify and use that one.

Second thing to do is not try to link against 2013 built libraries. If 2015 follows the same pattern as the older one, mixing libraries from different VS version is not possible.

Last thing, before adding icu, OpenSSL and MySQL you rather try to build Qt with the default parameters.

Comment: I am a litle beginner in Qt and programming... can you add a step by step instruction how to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Qt's current development version is 5.6.
It is in beta and there are prebuild binaries for msvc2015.

[Link to Qt Development Binaries](https://download.qt.io/development_releases/qt/5.6/)